# Sizing axis and Adding a constant line

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am creating a dashboard with some reports for an application i am building(using Telerik Reporting),

I've come across 2 questions:
The first being - i have some chart values which are sometimes positive and sometimes negative - if the data is both negative and positive - the autoscale feature works just fine, But if all data is negative - i'd still want to set the upper border of the yaxis to be something higher then 0, How would i go about this? (Autoscale on some cases, manual upper border on others)

Second question - i've craeted a point graph and i'd like to have a hardcoded "Line" at the 0 value (i'd like some points to be over 0 and some to be under - and the 0 should allways be there, just a constant line) - can i do that??? if so, how??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Question -

"A possible workaround would be to wire the ItemDataBound event of RadChart and keep track of the min and max value plotted (available through e.SeriesItem.YValue). Then, depending on their values compared to the baselineValue you can decide whether to keep the AutoScale feature (that would be if baselineValue is between min and max) or set AutoScale to false and manually define the axis range so that the marked zone is visible."

-[Per Telerik Employee as to conditionally keep or turn off AutoScale](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/chart/marked-zone-and-yaxis-autoscale-issue.aspx)

Second Question -

You want to use [marked zones](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/featuresmarkedzones.html) (mentioned above). They are located under PlotArea.MarkedZones. Inside the collection add a zone and set the ValueStartY to -1 and the ValueEndY  to 1.

This is basically Telerik's version of a StripLine which is a solid line you can add to normal SSRS reports.